# How do I use an #anchor to trigger a javascript script

Tags: html

I am using a pipedrive chatbot and have encoded it into my website. They give this code in their documentation to auto launch the chatbot and open the window. `LeadBooster.trigger('open');`

I am trying to make it  so when a `#chatbot` is at the end of the URL it runs the code trigger.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post out the code that you have tried and the SO communitiy will then help you to point out which part is having errors/needs to modify.

However, here's the solution based on your question descriptions.

```js
try{
  let get_anchor = location.hash;
  if(get_anchor=="chatbot"){
    //Do your thing here
  }
}catch(e){
  console.log("anchor not found");
}
```